# Ubuntu 22.04: RTL8821CE-based wifi not working

Tags: wireless, 22.04, realtek

I upgraded from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS.
PC has RTL8821CE wifi hardware on board.
On 20.04 wifi was working OK; on 22.04 no wifi.

Note: the PC when I bought it last year came with 20.04 pre-installed and at that time wifi was not working. On 20.04 I managed to make it work going through many posts. Now with 22.04 I can not succeed.

I went through many posts regarding the trouble with RTL8821CE but have apparently missed the key sequence of commands to correct things. Can someone dive into the infos I took (see attached) to try to understand what I can try to do to make wifi work?

Don't know if and how to attach a file with the infos I collected so I have to included them here below.

I don't "like" point 15 below with output like:
[    7.805121] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol __cfg80211_alloc_event_skb
[    7.805128] 8821ce: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_alloc_event_skb (err -22)
[    7.805140] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_register
[    7.805142] 8821ce: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err -22)

but I am not able to link these messages to specific actions I can try.

Thanks a lot and sorry for the long post :-)
Regards
Fred

fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$

fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ uname -r
5.15.0-60-generic

Here are the infos I took so far ( I only report RTL8821CE related infos).

1. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ sudo lshw

configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=Default string sku=CBL15C

```
   *-pci
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Gemini Lake PCI Express Root Port
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: f6
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:122 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:a1100000-a11fffff
       *-network UNCLAIMED
            description: Network controller
            product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
```

2. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ sudo lshw -short

/0/100/14/0                         network        RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

3. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ inxi -Fz
   Network:
   Device-1: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   driver: N/A   (seems to me there is no wifi driver !!!!!!?????)
4. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ lspci -knn | grep -A 2 -i net
   01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
   Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
   Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce, 8821ce
5. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ lspci -vvnn
   01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
   Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
   Control: I/O- Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
   Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- SERR- <PERR- INTx-
   Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 255
   Region 0: I/O ports at e000 [disabled] [size=256]
   Region 2: Memory at a1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
   Capabilities: 
   Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce, 8821ce
6. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ nmcli general
   STATE      CONNECTIVITY  WIFI-HW  WIFI       WWAN-HW  WWAN
   connected  full                          enabled      enabled   enabled          enabled
   fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$
7. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ nmcli connection
   NAME                  UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
   Wired connection 2    6caf9b67-1f13-31d3-aa8e-5c767b600758  ethernet  enx00e04c534458
   AC94-2.4GHz           1268664e-14fb-45d7-b5a4-125dde514150  wifi      --
   AC94-guest            49dfbe6e-52bb-4f6e-ad38-59692e24fcc1  wifi      --
   Fred Ulefone Note 9P  a748d918-1d11-4273-ae06-40b0ae93b14c  wifi      --
   H369A904462           67a7b8f9-ed9d-4a3a-a47d-a42c018ccfa5  wifi      --
   Wired connection 1    7ff51297-d011-3d6a-ae55-975bafee5f5b  ethernet  --

Question: If the wifi card does not work on 22.04, how can 22.04 know about the wifi networks I have? Info taken from the old 20.04 installation?

8. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ ifconfig   (= ifconfig -a)
   enx00e04c534458: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
   inet 192.168.1.95  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
   inet6 fe80::e7f4:a64e:41b4:6e76  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
   ether 00:e0:4c:53:44:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
   RX packets 3885  bytes 2900350 (2.9 MB)
   RX errors 30  dropped 5  overruns 6  frame 39
   TX packets 3781  bytes 1335914 (1.3 MB)
   TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enx1609010d2dc2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
ether 16:09:01:0d:2d:c2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
RX packets 13709  bytes 1120093 (1.1 MB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 13709  bytes 1120093 (1.1 MB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

That is: no wifi interface (like wlan0 for example)

9. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ rfkill list all
   0: hci0: Bluetooth
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
10. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ lshw -C network
    WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
    *-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Network controller
    product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
    version: 00
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:a1100000-a110ffff
11. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ dkms status
    backport-iwlwifi/9858, 5.15.0-58-generic, x86_64: installed
    backport-iwlwifi/9858, 5.15.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
    rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1~ppa, 5.15.0-58-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
    rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1~ppa, 5.15.0-60-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.13.0-35-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.13.0-37-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.13.0-39-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.13.0-40-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.13.0-41-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.13.0-44-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.13.0-48-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.13.0-51-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.13.0-52-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.15.0-41-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.15.0-46-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.15.0-48-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.15.0-50-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.15.0-52-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.15.0-53-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.15.0-56-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.15.0-57-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.15.0-58-generic, x86_64: built
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.15.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
    rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 5.6.11-microtech, x86_64: installed
    fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$
12. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ sudo apt install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
    Estrazione di linux-headers-5.15.0-60-generic (5.15.0-60.66) su (5.15.0-60.66)..
    .
    Configurazione di linux-headers-5.15.0-60-generic (5.15.0-60.66)...
    /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:

- dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.15.0-60-generic

8821ce.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
!!!!!Error! Module version v5.5.2_34066.20200325_COEX20180712-3232 for 8821ce.ko
is not newer than what is already found in kernel 5.15.0-60-generic (v5.5.2_3406
6.20200325_COEX20180712-3232).
You may override by specifying --force.

depmod....
...done.
Configurazione di dkms (2.8.7-2ubuntu2.1)...
Configurazione di git (1:2.34.1-1ubuntu1.8)...
Configurazione di build-essential (12.9ubuntu3)...
Elaborazione dei trigger per man-db (2.10.2-1)...
Cloning into 'rtl8821ce'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1777, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (112/112), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (81/81), done.
remote: Total 1777 (delta 47), reused 67 (delta 31), pack-reused 1665
Receiving objects: 100% (1777/1777), 5.98 MiB | 654.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (976/976), done.
About to run dkms install steps...
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20200325
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
Module rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325 already built for kernel 5.15.0-60-generic (x86_64).

8821ce.ko:
Running module version sanity check.

!!!!!Good news! Module version v5.5.2_34066.20200325_COEX20180712-3232 for 8821ce.ko
exactly matches what is already found in kernel 5.15.0-60-generic.
DKMS will not replace this module.
You may override by specifying --force.

depmod...
Finished running dkms install steps.

13. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
    Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
    Generazione albero delle dipendenze... Fatto
    Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
    rtl8821ce-dkms è già alla versione più recente (2:5.5.2.1~focal10).
    0 aggiornati, 0 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 0 non aggiornati.
    fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$

It says that rtl8821ce-dkms already is at the most recent version (2:5.5.2.1~focal10)

14. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ ls -al /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms
    total 9572
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 feb 15 12:17 .
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096 feb 10 11:08 ..
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3844525 feb 10 11:08 8821ce.ko
15. fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$ sudo dmesg | grep 8821
    [    7.805121] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol __cfg80211_alloc_event_skb
    [    7.805128] 8821ce: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_alloc_event_skb (err -22)
    [    7.805140] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_register
    [    7.805142] 8821ce: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err -22)
    [    7.805154] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired
    [    7.805155] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired (err -22)
    [    7.805188] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_vendor_cmd_reply
    [    7.805189] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_vendor_cmd_reply (err -22)
    [    7.805206] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_del_sta_sinfo
    [    7.805207] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_del_sta_sinfo (err -22)
    [    7.805220] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_unregister
    [    7.805221] 8821ce: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err -22)
    [    7.805265] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_ch_switch_notify
    [    7.805266] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ch_switch_notify (err -22)
    [    7.805279] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz
    [    7.805280] 8821ce: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz (err -22)
    [    7.805298] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_ready_on_channel
    [    7.805299] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ready_on_channel (err -22)
    [    7.805343] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_free
    [    7.805344] 8821ce: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err -22)
    [    7.805350] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_new_nm
    [    7.805351] 8821ce: Unknown symbol wiphy_new_nm (err -22)
    [    7.805358] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_get_bss
    [    7.805359] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_get_bss (err -22)
    [    7.805385] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol __cfg80211_send_event_skb
    [    7.805387] 8821ce: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_send_event_skb (err -22)
    [    7.805409] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_disconnected
    [    7.805410] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_disconnected (err -22)
    [    7.805419] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_michael_mic_failure
    [    7.805420] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_michael_mic_failure (err -22)
    [    7.805430] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_ibss_joined
    [    7.805431] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ibss_joined (err -22)
    [    7.805483] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_scan_done
    [    7.805484] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_scan_done (err -22)
    [    7.805498] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_roamed
    [    7.805499] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_roamed (err -22)
    [    7.805503] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_put_bss
    [    7.805504] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_put_bss (err -22)
    [    7.805521] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_connect_done
    [    7.805522] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_connect_done (err -22)
    [    7.805543] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_unlink_bss
    [    7.805545] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unlink_bss (err -22)
    [    7.805560] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_frame_data
    [    7.805561] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_frame_data (err -22)
    [    7.805572] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_new_sta
    [    7.805573] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_new_sta (err -22)
    [    7.805589] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol __cfg80211_alloc_reply_skb
    [    7.805590] 8821ce: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_alloc_reply_skb (err -22)
    [    7.805601] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory
    [    7.805602] 8821ce: Unknown symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory (err -22)
    [    7.805609] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_mgmt_tx_status
    [    7.805610] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_mgmt_tx_status (err -22)
    [    7.805615] 8821ce: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_rx_mgmt_khz
    [    7.805616] 8821ce: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_mgmt_khz (err -22)
    [    7.812602] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=8821
    [    7.813588] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_fw.bin
    [    7.815764] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8821c_config.bin
    fred@fred-CoreBookLite:~$

Comment: Please start with: `sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms` Reboot and let us see: `sudo dmesg | grep 8821` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please check it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

We notice this in your `sudo dkms status`:

> `backport-iwlwifi/9858, 5.15.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed`

I believe that `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` installs its own custom version of `cfg80211` among possibly others. It conflicts with the version usually found in the kernel and which your installed driver *`8821ce`* is built to use.

Since you have no Intel wireless device, which uses iwlwifi, I suggest that you remove the conflicting driver suite:

```
sudo apt purge backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Reboot. Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Hello!!! Sorry for coming back this late - was in bed with flu.The solution you provided works! I have wifi now. Thanks a lot.