# RTL8821CE wifi stopped working after 15-Feb-23 22.04 update and restart

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

My problem seems to be very similar to that detailed at [Ubuntu 22.04: RTL8821CE-based wifi not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455128/ubuntu-22-04-rtl8821ce-based-wifi-not-working) but the fix there (removing backport-iwlwifi-dkms) did not work for me (I apparently do not have backport-iwlwifi-dkms on my computer).

I had run into an issue with this wifi card long (more than a year, I think) ago, and had resolved it, but I seem to be dead in the water again.

I am currently accessing the internet with an old usb dongle, which is not very good (no 5G).

Any computer savvy-ness I ever had is probably 30 years out of date, so please forgive my cluelessness.

Any help appreciated.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` :

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: SK hynix Gold P31 SSD [1c5c:174a]
    Subsystem: SK hynix Gold P31 SSD [1c5c:174a]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Kernal version is 5.19.0-32-generic

Output of `grep rtw88_8821ce /etc/modprobe.d/*` :

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:blacklist rtw88_8821ce
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: It looks like the `rtw88_8821ce` isn't loaded for some reason. What is the kernel version?

Comment: Kernal version is 5.19.0-32-generic

Comment: You probably installed a 3rd party driver and blacklisted `rtw88_8821ce`. Please add output of `grep rtw88_8821ce /etc/modprobe.d/*`. And the old driver needs to be reinstalled.

Comment: Yes; following another string about the RTL8821CE at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401475/why-rtl8821ce-or-wifi-is-removed-during-kernel-update-on-20-04-4-lts I did pretty much exactly what you noted.

output of grep rtw88_8821ce /etc/modprobe.d/*

/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:blacklist rtw88_8821ce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've blacklisted the `rtw88_8821ce` module when installing some other driver.

Now when kernel upgraded from 5.15 to 5.19 that driver installed from source didn't build.

You can remove that `blacklist rtw88_8821ce` from `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and run

```
sudo modprobe rtw88_8821ce
```

If you aren't satisfied with the in-tree module performance when considering to install some other driver, make sure it is compatible with the 5.19 kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Pilot6. I'm going to reboot and disconnect my usb wifi dongle and see where I end up.

Comment: You can do it without reboot.

Comment: Wifi up and running!Thanks very much, Pilot6.

SOLVED

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as Joseph: after installing updates (in particular: the latest kernel 5.19....), wifi was gone.

Here is how I (apparently) solved it:
I rebooted and chose the previous kernel version (5.15...), wifi was working again.

I removed rtl8821ce-dkms

```
sudo apt remove rtl8821ce-dkms
```

then rebooted into the latest kernel 5.19... wifi was working again.

Comment: You could remove it without booting with a previous kernel.

Answer (score 0):

after kernel update to 5.19 my wifi adapter rtl8821ce got disabled

I updated kernel to 6.1.12-060112-generic

installed latest version of driver from https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce

added to blacklist rtw88_8821ce (because with this driver wifi signal is weak)

Now my wifi works well

Comment: Why would you install a mainline kernel for that?

Comment: There are troubles with wifi driver and kernel 5.19, looks like something about dkms. With kernel 5.15 wifi worked well too.