# 22.04 LTS wifi not working: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110

Tags: 22.04, iwlwifi

hardware: beelink mini PC U59

OS: ubuntu 22.04 lts

```
uname -r: 5.15.0-82-generic

dpkg -s linux-firmware | grep - i version: 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.18

lspci | grep -i network: controller IntelCorporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160 MHz (rev 01)
```

Problem: wifi is not working

After a (re)boot and thus also in dmesg an error is seen: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110

I already tried to install backport-iwlwifi-dkms, but after a reboot the same error occurs.

Since wifi still didn't work and based on what is written [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1455128/ubuntu-22-04-rtl8821ce-based-wifi-not-working) I removed dkms.
Having done that, the output of dmesg|grep iwl can be find [here](https://files.fm/f/w2sebmwhf)

Later: thanks to the reply of [chili555](https://askubuntu.com/users/19421/chili555). I installed (with the mainline kernel script) the latest version (v6.5.1) and problem has been solved

Comment: Is this a dual-boot with Windows? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled I think you'll have better luck with a newer kernel version and firmware: https://tuxcare.com/blog/ubuntu-22-04-3-is-here-with-linux-kernel-6-2/

Comment: No it is ubuntu only; no dual boot

Comment: later: I installed the mainline kernel script as mention in the link you provided. I installed (with that script) the latest kernel which is v6.5.1 (September 2, 2023) and the problem seems to be solved, Thanks !!!